# Building custom Installation-Package-Builder using visual studio's "Setup and Deployment" feature

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

Currently I am using Visual Studio’s feature “Setup and Deployment” to create installation package (Setup.MSI/Setup.exe file). As the part of building installation process, I put all required files (such as DLL, EXE, MDBs etc.) in a specific folder, and build installation package (MSI / EXE file). Since this process requires knowledge on how to use Visual Studio, I cannot simply ask anyone to build installation package for me.   Therefore I wanted to build some custom installation builder (MSI/EXE builder) utilizing Visual Studio’s “Setup and Deployment”. The purpose of this “MSI/EXE builder” to give ability to build/rebuild installation packet without knowing anything about Visual Studio or programming skill. So s/he can generate installation packet by dropping provided all required file in specific folder structure, and pushing a button to regenerate installation package.

Can somebody point me where to start? Is there any API exist to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studios wdproj files are not fully scriptable via MSBuild.

The recommended way to accomplish this task is to use WIX.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_index.htm

You can then build the project using MSBuild commands (which you could write an application to do)

Comment: Kuffs,
Thank you for WIX link. I certainly appreciate for providing me the link. 
Is there way I can create initial setup-deployment template using Visual-Studio as you would do normally, and then create a windows App to use that template build Setup.MSI or Setup.exe using Visual Studio’s component? Is there any way we can interact Visual-Studio Setup-Deployment component from our custom application via API call?

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to do what you ask. I know of no converter than can convert S&D projects to Wix format.  MSBuild is the automation system for building projects. It is what Visual Studio itself uses.